# What is the proper MVC design for a UITableView inside a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

As the title describes, I've got a tableview inside each of my collection view cells. For me, it makes sense that the superview's controller should control the view, but since in this case each tableview contains different data, I have made each superview (collection view cell) the controller for its tableview. I hope that makes sense. I know making a view to also be a controller violates the MVC paradigm, but I'm not sure what the proper way is achieve MVC compliance in this case. I also need to send messages to the table view based on what happens in the CollectionViewController. Do I need to subclass UITableViewController and make a reference to it in my collectionviewcell.h file?

Sorry if that was confusing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you handle the tableview logic in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your instinct is correct that having a view object serve as a data source is a violation of MVC. I would suggest having the owning view controller either serve as the data source for all the table views, or set up a separate model object for each table view that serves up the cells for that table view.

If you use a single data source you'll have to have a switch statement that figures out which table view is asking and fills the cells with the appropriate data.

My gut would be to create a thin table view data source class who's only job is to serve up the cells for the table view inside a collection cell (and respond to the other collection view data source protocol methods). Use a custom subclass of UICollectionViewCell that has a strong property that points to the data source object. You could make your custom cell class create an empty data source object at init time and hook up it's outlet to the table view.

Then in your cellForItemAtIndexPath method, pass the appropriate data to the cell's data source object. If you reuse a cell, it would already have a data source object, so you'd just replace the data with new data and trigger the reloadData method.

Your controller object would mediate between the model and the view, like it should. It would set up the model data for each cell, and then the data source object for each cell would act as the model for that cells table view.

If you later come up with several different types of collection cells that display different data, using separate data source objects for each cell would keep the code simple. You'd just subclass your data source object based on the cell type.

Comment: Since the number of collection view cells containing table view will vary based on user interaction, I know a switch statement isn't the way to go. But I like the solution you gave afterwards about using a custom collection view cell to set the datasource for its table view and that's it. I'm curious though about my CustomCollectionViewCell.h and .m files: are those files considered controllers and the view is in the actual nib? Or are those files considered to be just part of "View" -- the "code-behind" if you will for the view in the nib?

Comment: No, your CustomCollectionViewCell defines a custom subclass of UIView. The .m file is the code behind that class. The .xib file defines the structure of the views inside that view class. The .h, .m, and .xib files are all combined together to create your view object. (A collection view subclass, in this case.)